# Selenium Webdriver ruby upgrade (write_timeout error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm trying to upgrade from ruby 2.4.4 to ruby 2.6.1, and none of my Javascript-enabled cucumber tests work. I get the following error when running a cucumber test:

```
      unknown keyword: write_timeout (ArgumentError)
      ./features/support/env.rb:58:in `block in <top (required)>'
      ./features/support/sign_in_step_helper.rb:4:in `sign_in'
      ./features/step_definitions/session_steps.rb:2:in `"I log in"'
      features/quote_wizard/quotes_wizard.feature:40:in `When I log in'
```

`write_timeout` does not exist anywhere in the entire project.

This is what I have in my `features/support/env.rb` (auto-generated comments suppressed):

```
require 'simplecov'
require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rspec/doubles'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require_relative './download_helper
SimpleCov.at_exit do
  puts 'Simplecov complete'
end

Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5 

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
    args: %w[no-sandbox disable-extensions headless] # Remove `headless` to view test runs in browser
  ) 
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
  options.add_preference(:download,
                         directory_upgrade:   true,
                         prompt_for_download: false,
                         default_directory:   DownloadHelper::DEFAULT_DIR)

  options.add_preference(:browser, set_download_behavior: { behavior: 'allow' })

  driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)

  bridge = driver.browser.send(:bridge)

  path = '/session/:session_id/chromium/send_command'
  path[':session_id'] = bridge.session_id

  bridge.http.call(:post,
                   path,
                   cmd:    'Page.setDownloadBehavior',
                   params: {
                     behavior:     'allow',
                     downloadPath: DownloadHelper::DEFAULT_DIR
                   })
  driver
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome

ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

:truncation instead.
begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end

require 'constant_tables'
ConstantTables.load!
Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation, { except: ConstantTables.table_names }
World(FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods)
```

EDIT: here is the test part of the Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'parallel_tests'
  gem 'site_prism'
  gem 'capybara-email'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rubocop-rails'
  gem 'rubocop-rspec'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'chronic'
  gem 'sinatra', '~> 2.0.0.rc2'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
  gem 'paratrooper', '3.0.2'
  gem 'platform-api', '2.0'
  gem 'activerecord-import'
  gem 'rb-readline'
end
```

Comment: Can you share your gemfile?

Comment: Just the test part, you mentioned your app runs right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should upgrade your gems, check this out:

[webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

They specifically added support for ruby 2.6, maybe is worth the try? Have you checked the others?